# Android Studio go back to Main Activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

I am trying to develop a puzzle game. Each activity has an image and four buttons as answer. I want when user click on wrong answer message appears and after that go back to main activity.

My code is:

`public void mess1(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry! Better Luck Next Time", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(this, "You Won Nothing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        managerOfSound(y);
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }`

But after clicking Toast and sound work but MainActivity doesn't start.
Please help me, what is wrong with the code?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you posted. Are you getting an error? If so, please post it.

Comment: There is no error in the code but as I stated that Message shows correctly, sound works perfectly but MainActivity doesn't starts. I think the last 2 lines of code could not be implemented.

Comment: I understand that there is no compiler error, but the code should start the activity. If it doesn't, there should be a runtime error, which you can view in the `Android Monitor`

Comment: I reviewed in Android Monitor but it says

Comment: 04-30 02:17:13.638 20991-20991/owaismeethani.com.abc V/ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{33458a4f token=android.os.BinderProxy@38287b9 {owaismeethani.com.abc/owaismeethani.com.abc.japan}} show : true
04-30 02:17:29.018 20991-20991/owaismeethani.com.abc I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@38287b9 time:14357308
04-30 02:17:43.948 20991-20991/owaismeethani.com.abc V/ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{33458a4f token=android.os.BinderProxy@38287b9 {owaismeethani.com.abc/owaismeethani.com.abc.japan}} show : true

Comment: As I understood Android Monitor didn't show any error